# Configurar Virtual Host do Laravel no ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, virtualhost, host

Quando eu acesso um projeto que não utiliza laravel, funciona normal, mas quando acesso algum que usa, não carrega nada e mostra uma tela vazia. A configuração dele tem que ser diferente dos outros?

Meu virtual host está assim:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/insidetv/public/" 
   ServerName insidetv.local 
   ServerAlias insidetv.local 
   ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/insidetv-error.log" 
   CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/insidetv-custom.log" common
   <Directory "/var/www/html/insidetv/public/"> 
      Options Includes FollowSymLinks 
      AllowOverride All 
      Order allow,deny 
      Allow from all 
   </Directory> 
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Se você inserir um ServerName localhost   
em qualquer um httpd.conf ou apache2.conf em /etc/apache2 e reinicie o apache, o aviso desaparecerá. Está rodando sobre distro Ubuntu ? Qual a versão?

Comment: Coloquei o servername, mas na hora de dar restart aparece; apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this

Comment: Estou usando o Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Alterei o arquivo insidetv.conf para isso: <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName insidetv.conf
  DocumentRoot "/home/vagrant/insidetv/public"
  <Directory "/home/vagrant/insidetv/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Agora o apache faz restart, mas quando tento acessar insidetv.local, mostra o seguinte: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Verifique permissão sobre a pasta do usuário, verifique qual usuário foi criado o diretório em home

Comment: Acabei reinstalando o ubuntu pq estava dando mtos problemas

Comment: Atualizei o post com o problema que esta dando agora.